# Python API sentinelsat error in query intersect

Tags: python, api, intersect, sentinelsat

I'm facing a problem when searching for an image that contains specific coordinates. I can't get the intersect function to work with the API.

**I'm getting this error message:**

```
sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: HTTP status 200 OK: Invalid query string. Check the parameters and format.
```

so how can i get the query to work with intersection ??

**Code used:**

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date
from shapely.geometry import box, Polygon

api = SentinelAPI('myusername', 'mypassword','https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')

footprint='footprint:"intersects(POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)))"'

products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=('20180901', date(2018, 9, 3)),
                     area_relation='Intersects',
                     platformname='Sentinel-2',
                     cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 10))

print(products)

#this works  
#api.download_all(products)
```

**Any idea how to solve this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace

```
footprint='footprint:"intersects(POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)))"'
```

with

```
footprint='POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'
```

I don't know if these numbers are just for reference here but there are no results for this Polygon. To see results for another area try

```
footprint='POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'
products = api.query(footprint,
                 date=('20180901', date(2018, 9, 5)),
                 area_relation='Intersects',
                 platformname='Sentinel-2',
                cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 10))
```

According to official sentinelsat [docs](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=intersect), you can select between three different types of area_relation inside your query. I think you should leave footprint only containing the Polygon:

> ```
> Intersects: true if the AOI and the footprint intersect (default)
> Contains: true if the AOI is inside the footprint
> IsWithin: true if the footprint is inside the AOI
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like other OpenGIS implementations, I think you need to quote the polygon section, i.e. intersects('POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))')

Comment: it gave this error
   footprint='intersects('POLYGON((0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))')'
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax